# AEM 6.3: Login using Oauth

Tags: oauth, aem

I am trying to create an Oauth login functionality on an AEM website. Currently, I am going to try it on local publish environment. I have learned that AEM provides Twitter and Facebook implementations. I am interested in implementing the Twitter oauth login functionality.

I have gone through some articles like :

https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/communities/using/social-login.html
https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-3/communities/using/sites-console.html

I have never done anything like this before. So, I am having trouble figuring out the complete picture. Like do I need to create a login component? I tried to follow the implementation given on we retail site. But the login component provided seems to be a little complicated and I Want to create my own login component. I want to know if I have to create my own login component then what are the properties I would need to provide in the dialog, like the path etc or maybe any keys? As given in the article I have created a twitter app, created a Twitter connect cloud service, configured AEM Communities Twitter OAuth Provider, published Cloud Service, configured Adobe Granite OAuth Application and Provider but I am still not able to see the whole picture here. Like how does everything connects starting from a login component?

There are a lot of questions here but to simply put I am just confused.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This is one resource I've found : https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/kt/platform-repository/using/oauth-code-sample-develop.html.  It hints towards the following flowchart:

[image]

Good Luck...